# RabbitMQ Example Code Not Compiling In Java

Tags: java, rabbitmq

[image]I started the RabbitMQ Java based interference recently and I see that the Producer part of the code was compiling, but the Consumer part of the code is not compiling as expected. This is the URL that I am referring to: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-java.html

Specifically, this is the receiver code from the website: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-tutorials/blob/master/java/Recv.java

Thanks,
Pavan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are using Java 1.8 and above?

Comment: I see that it is using 1.7; Looks like there is a dependency on which version of Eclipse could actually identify and start using 1.8 as well. So I switched to the latest eclipse version and updated the compiler settings to 1.8 and see that the Lambda compilation is resolved.